# obtain the MAC Address/interface name from GUID on FreeBSD?

Tags: freebsd, ethernet

Is there any way I can obtain the MAC Address/interface name from GUID on FreeBSD? Are there any system calls to do that? I was searching everywhere but couldn't find any information. Can you please help?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Best Regards, Marc.

Answer (score 1):

N.B.: outside the windows world, GUID is known as UUID.

The startup script `/etc/rc.d/hostid` first tries to get the UUID from the SMBIOS. If that fails it turns to the `uuidgen` program to generate a UUID. This program uses the [`uuidgen`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=uuidgen&apropos=0&sektion=2&manpath=FreeBSD%209.1-RELEASE&arch=default&format=html) system call. As you can read in the manual page, the last 6-byte block of the UUID is the hardware address of one of the physical network interfaces of the system.

**Note** that if no interface exists, a *random* multi-cast address is used instead! So the UUID doesn't necessarily contain a hardware address.

Both the SMBIOS and `uuidgen` UUIDs generally use the hardware address of the first on-board ethernet chip.

Probably the easiest way to get the interface name and the hardware address is to use the SIOCGIFSTATUS ioctl, as it is done in the `status()` function in [`ifconfig`](http://svnweb.freebsd.org/base/release/9.1.0/sbin/ifconfig/ifconfig.c?revision=243808&view=markup).